# Implement typeahead search with links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I would like to make a typeahead that searches from `Items.all`, `Objects.all`, and `Stuff.all` (probably a total of a thousand or so things that do not really change) and the suggestions brought up by the typeahead are links such that when they are clicked, take you to their page, just like `<= link_to Item.name, Item %>` does.

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I'm using bootstrap, so it seems I have to modify bootstrap-typeahead's behavior somehow.

I'm wondering maybe if there's an efficient way to do this so that the list of Items, Objects, and Stuff are all loaded once and kept client-side or something, then the typeahead box could be on every page of the application and work the same.

Just like Twitter's site where their typeahead search retrieves links when you search for people, and one just has to click the links that appear below the text box to go to the page.

Comment: Not really sure but is this something like that you're looking for ? http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: In those demos none of them function like I described where the suggestions are clickable links that take you to their corresponding view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the `rabl` gem to generate json files containing data from my model and the `twitter-typeahead-rails` gem to implement twitter's [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with the [soulmate](https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate) gem.